# How to bring a Application on To via httpListener?

Tags: c#

i have the problem bringing another Application ( Prepar3D v4.4 = FS ) to front and send some Keystrokes to this.
The Problem is to bring the FS to front via a HttpListener.
I try to explain:
FS is running ( possible in the Background )
My Application runs ALWAYS in Background ( not as Icon ) and listening for http calls via a HttpListener.
Another Applitaion sends a http request to my application and then ( the Problem ) my Application must Bring the FS Window to Front and make it the active window. Then my Application must send some Keystrokes to FS.

Now, in my Application i have a Funktion to bring the FS Window on Top and send some Keystrokes. When i call this funktion via a Button click from my Application all works fine. FS will get the Focus and become active and the Keystroke is send. Fs recives the Keystroke.

But when my Application recives the request via the HttpListenre and call exactly the same funktion it will not work.

Can anyone help here ?

Thanks
Matthias

Comment: what method do you use for set FS window active?

Comment: First do a compare and make sure the characters you are sending are exactly the same include any terminating characters.

Comment: what exactly does not work? bringing the FS window to front or just sending the keystrokes?

Comment: Hello,i tried different like :        IntPtr FS_FOCUS(string fs)
        {
            Process[] SameProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("Prepar3D");
            IntPtr windowHandle = SameProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;

            if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Prepar3D is not running.");
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            ShowWindow(windowHandle, WindowState.ShowNormal);
            SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);

            return windowHandle;
        }
and also BringWindowToTop, SetWindowPos

Comment: What exactly not oork is to bring the FS Window on top and make it the active windew

Comment: I call exactly the same method i used for the button , i hve added to my Application for testing. So with a Button from my Application it works, but not when this method is clled from the HttpListener